# How to configuration Elastic Search

Tags: java, distributed, elasticsearch

We are running elastic search on two servers with a load balancer, I just want to know what is the best server configurations where I can work on that server with minimal problems.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say but if you have a no limit budget, I would say :

- The more amount of RAM you can have (let's say 128 Gb)
- The fastest hard disks (SSD)

It depends on your docs. How many docs you will have? What kind of queries you are going to run ( are you going to use facets, sorting ) ?

One comment: why do you think you need a load balancer?

Comment: I want to configure for realtime searching with minimal risk.( fail over...) . If I have 3 servers, and my docs at least 1 milion website per day were crawler. I just want to ask what is the best of configure about number of SHARDS, replicas, MEMORY, HEAP_MEM.......I known ES has supported load balancer in their core :D